# API is showing any records using fetch, axios but postman shows. Can someone please check what is the problem in the fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this error when I fetch the api in the console log

Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body. But I am sending post only. Please see

```
    const data = { provider_service_id: "62" };

    fetch("https://paw5.digiinteracts.in/api/user/provider/service/edit", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer 157|tQnUEQKp5O372v4faKHC1b9mOWLMVGmh6gjPawHN"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("Success:", data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  };
```

I have tried the same in the codesandbox and it does not show any error

https://codesandbox.io/s/test-post-fetch-api-forked-nh7dm2?file=/src/App.js

Postman shows records

[https://web.postman.co/workspace/My-Workspace~501189d7-e449-46e4-800c-691ce823563d/request/create?requestId=a0a568d7-a28b-4815-aa16-6480cf6d15df](https://web.postman.co/workspace/My-Workspace%7E501189d7-e449-46e4-800c-691ce823563d/request/create?requestId=a0a568d7-a28b-4815-aa16-6480cf6d15df)

Comment: I successfully get a response in your code sandbox.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am getting success but 0 data in an array. But in postman I am getting 2 in the data.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, instead of the header:

'Accept': 'application/json',

I put this one and it worked

'Content-Type': 'application/json',